# How do I enable tailwind intellsense in Visual Studio 2022 preview?

Tags: visual-studio, tailwind-css, visual-studio-2022

I tried to add the code below in the *.esproj file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="node_modules\tailwindcss\dist\*.css" />
    <None Include="node_modules\@tailwindcss\forms\dist\*.css" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Visual Studio is able to pick up the default Tailwind CSS, but the IntelliSense does not pick up the additional CSS I defined in the tailwind.config.js.

Comment: I haven't checked the latest VS 2022 preview version. Is the Razor Experimental editor turned on in the preview options? If so, I would suggest trying to disable it and see if that helps.

Comment: I am editing HTML files. I created a standalone TypeScript Angular Template project and installed tailwind CSS. But the IntelliSense does not pick up the extra classes I defined in tailwind.config.js in HTML files.

Comment: yes I understood.  is this turned on, or off? try toggling it and see if you get a better result. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/01/26/~/media/ECG/visualstudiomagazine/Images/2020/07/enable_razor_editor.ashx

Comment: I cannot find that option in Visual Studio 2022 preview. It is probably in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: The Visual Studio CSS editor (which is what provides class name intellisense in both HTML and Razor) doesn't know anything about tailwind; it just looks at the .css files in your project.

Comment: @Jimmy yeah, I think the question comes to where I can find the generated .css file based on the tailwind.config.js.

Answer (score 3):

Now there is an extension for Tailwind CSS Intellisense in Visual Studio 2022.

Here is the github repo: [Tailwind CSS VS2022 Support](https://github.com/theron-wang/VS2022-Editor-Support-for-Tailwind-CSS)

You can also download it from marketplace: [Download From Market Place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheronWang.TailwindCSSIntellisense)

Here is the get start guide: [Getting Started](https://github.com/theron-wang/VS2022-Editor-Support-for-Tailwind-CSS/blob/main/Getting-Started.md)

Happy Coding...